# What is the difference between an RPM debuginfo package and rebuilding a package with an option like -g?

Tags: package-management, rpm, debugging

I would like some clarification on how debuginfo packages from RPM are used. Say I have the package `vim`, and I found a crash. I want to debug this crash, but in `gdb` I am getting errors about `gdb` not having access to line number information. In my mind, I have 2 options:

1. Install the debuginfo package
2. Re-build and install the `vim` rpm with `CFLAGS`, `CXXFLAGS`, and `LDFLAGS` with `-g3` or something similar.

I've recently tried option #1 and I still get some errors about missing symbols from gdb, which prompted this question as I was making some assumptions about what debuginfo packages are and how they are used. Would you please explain the differences between option 1 and 2 I listed above, or in the case I'm incorrect, how to properly accomplish this?

Comment: What are the errors that you get *after* installing the `debuginfo` package?

Answer (score 0):

> I've recently tried option #1 and I still get some errors about missing symbols from gdb, which prompted this question as I was making some assumptions about what debuginfo packages are and how they are used.

The crash might not be in the application itself but e.g. in glibc or any other library vim depends on. Which means you have to install debuginfo packages for all the relevant libraries.

Which also means that building vim from sources will most likely lead to the same issue: some debug symbols not resolving. Also if you build a package yourself, your compilation flags will be different than those used by Fedora and then you may or may not get the same crash.

Answer (score 0):

@Artem is correct - you need to have debuginfo of all transitive dependencies.

It may be painful to find all of them. You can easy that using ABRT (`dnf install abrt`). When something crashes it is recorded by ABRT. E.g. on my system:

```
$ abrt     
071eb9c 1x /usr/libexec/mysqld 2020-06-24 00:55:09
7552a02 1x mariadb 2020-06-26 15:37:45
$ abrt backtrace 071eb9c
Problem has no backtrace
Start retracing process? [y/N] y
Upload core dump and perform remote retracing? (It may contain sensitive data). If your answer is 'No', a stack trace will be generated locally. Local retracing requires downloading potentially large amount of debuginfo data [y/N] n
Local retracing
Analyzing coredump 'coredump'
Cleaning cache...
Cache cleaning has finished
...
```